# Please, what is the name of this plant?

Tags: identification, indoors, containers

I bought this beautiful plant on a village marketplace, but I have no idea what name it possesses. If someone knows the answer, please, do help me. Thank you!!!

[image]

Comment: Looks like Musa plant (banana).

Comment: Another possibility is Hosta, but this needs to grow a little more before any real answer can be given. Do you have a more up-to-date picture?

Comment: Can you give us a updated picture.  There has been plenty of time for change in the growth, better to identify.

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s either a musa (banana), Cana, or Ginger. It’s hard to tell between those three it being too juvenile to tell. I think I can say it at least is not a Dwarf Cavendish, that generally has a dark red staining close to the central part of the leaves, especially when young.

Comment: I believe it is a Musa.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a plant from family [Zingiberaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zingiberaceae).

In my humble opinion, of species Curcuma.

Perhaps turmeric, *Curcuma longa*.

If and when your plant produces flowers (weeks, months or even years), please post a photo and we will be able to identify with more certainty.

PS
If I am correct, your plant will...

- quickly outgrow the pot you have it in now;
- require very little water in the cooler months;
- require a lot of water in warmer months and regular feeding with liquid organic fertiliser and / or seaweed tonic.

Answer (score -1):

[Lily of the Valley](https://www.newhousenewhomenewlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/lily-of-valley-03-1024x768.jpg)

I think that this is Lily of the Valley. Convallaria majalis  Great shade and high ground cover plant.  Lucky you!  Toxic to cats especially.

[image: lily of the valley]

Comment: I am not sure - the asker’s plant is bigger, with broader leaves and the down bend of the outer leaves isn’t lily-of-the-valley-ish either.

Comment: I am  thinking aspidistra. The Lilly of valley leaves are not glossy.

Comment: Second guess ; spathiphyllum - peace lilly

Comment: Could be Peace Lily for sure.

Comment: Looks a lot like a dwarf canna.